# Output data by putting lag in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, lag

I have one table as below in SQL Server like below.

```
SELECT * FROM OverlappingDateRanges
```

```
Id          startDate                       EndDate
10001   2020-04-01 00:00:00.000     2020-05-25 00:00:00.000
10001   2020-05-26 00:00:00.000     2020-07-15 00:00:00.000
10001   2020-07-17 00:00:00.000     2020-08-15 00:00:00.000
10001   2020-08-16 00:00:00.000     2020-10-15 00:00:00.000
10001   2020-10-16 00:00:00.000     2020-12-31 00:00:00.000
10002   2020-05-01 00:00:00.000     2020-05-29 00:00:00.000
10002   2020-05-30 00:00:00.000     2020-07-08 00:00:00.000
10002   2020-07-09 00:00:00.000     2020-10-01 00:00:00.000
10002   2020-10-03 00:00:00.000     2020-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

---

I want output like below where if there is no date difference between end date and next start date of same id, then then date will continue & its should break if end date and next start date is not in continue.

Output should be:

```
  id          startDate                endDate
10001  2020-04-01 00:00:00.000    2020-07-15 00:00:00.000
10001  2020-07-17 00:00:00.000    2020-12-31 00:00:00.000
10002  2020-05-01 00:00:00.000    2020-10-01 00:00:00.000
10002  2020-10-03 00:00:00.000    2020-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Identify where each output row starts by looking at the previous end.  Then do a cumulative sum and aggregate:

```
select id, min(startdate), max(enddate)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_enddate >= dateadd(day, -1, startdate) then 0 else 1
                 end) over (partition by id order by startdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(enddate) over (partition by id order by startdate) as prev_enddate
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec203c2ddd7ea07db6aa04b8295fa235) is a db<>fiddle.